ESP32 and Laravel Project Communication
I'm trying to send a command to ESP32. I'm using Xampp to run my Laravel project which is outside my xampp htdocs. My Laravel Project works fine even if its outside htdocs but when I try to give command to ESP32 I kept getting 404 Error Code. Please help.
This is my laravel index page:
<form action="{{ route('irrigation.esp32') }}" method="POST" class="text-center">            
@csrf
   <input type="hidden" name="command" value="activate">
   <button type="submit"> Activate </button>        
</form>

This is my web or route:
Route::post('/irrigation_control/esp32/action', [IrrigationControlController::class, 'controlSystem'])->name('irrigation.esp32');

This is my controller:
public function controlSystem(Request $request) {

   $action = $request->input('command');

   $esp32Url = 'http://<ip-address>/irrigation_control/esp32/command'; 


   try {

      $response = Http::timeout(60)->post($esp32Url, ['action' => $action]);

      if ($response->successful()) {

          if($action == 'activate'){

               $message = 'System ' . ($action === 'activate' ? 'activated!' : 'deactivated!');
           }
      } else {
                
        $message = "Failed to communicate with ESP32!!!". $response->status() . $response->body();
        return redirect()->route('irrigation.index')->with('message', $message);

      }

   } 
   catch (\Exception $e) {
            $message = 'Error communicating with ESP32: ' . $e->getMessage();
   }


   return redirect()->route('irrigation.index')->with('message', $message);
}'


This is my ESP32 code:
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "<wifiname>";
const char* password = "<wifipass>";

const char* serverName = "http://<ip-address>/irrigation_control/esp32/command";

const int PIN_RELAY = 4;
const int PIN_LED = 32;
const int PIN_SENSOR = 35;

const int dryThreshold = 3000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  pinMode(PIN_RELAY, OUTPUT);     
  pinMode(PIN_LED, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY, LOW);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  Serial.print("Connecting to");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    digitalWrite(PIN_LED, LOW);
    Serial.print("Connecting to Wifi...");
    delay(1000);
  }

  digitalWrite(PIN_LED, HIGH);
  
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop(){

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
    HTTPClient http;

    http.begin(serverName);

    int httpResponseCode = http.GET(); 

    if (httpResponseCode > 0) {

      String command = http.getString();
      Serial.print("\n HTTP Response Code:" + String(httpResponseCode));
      Serial.println("\n Command received: " + command);

      if (command == "activate") {

         int moistureLevel = analogRead(PIN_SENSOR);
         Serial.print("Soil Moisture Level: ");
         Serial.println(moistureLevel);

         if (moistureLevel > dryThreshold) {

           digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY, HIGH);
           Serial.println("\n Soil is dry. Activating relay.");
         }
         else{
           digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY, LOW);
           Serial.println("\n Soil is moist. Relay is off.");
         }
      }
    }
    else {
      Serial.print("\n Error on sending POST: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    }
    http.end();
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(PIN_LED, LOW);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(PIN_LED, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Wifi Disconnected");
  }  
   delay(10000);
}

This is what I get:
HTTP Response Code:404
Command received:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.2.12 Server at 192.168.68.109 Port 80</address>
</body></html>

I want my ESP32 to listen and do to the command sent by Laravel

All the esp32 code you've written is for sending a HTTP request, not receiving one. You're on completely the wrong track.

This sort of thing might get you started (I just googled "esp32 webserver"): https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-web-server-arduino-ide/

The error message shows that your Apache setup is expecting incoming request with SSL (and probably on port 443), i.e. a HTTPS request, but your ESP32 is sending an non-secure HTTP request on port 80... See how to use HTTPS with BasicHttpsClient example.
